# Deserialize JSON with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, request, deserialization

I'm using RestSharp to make a request.

The request returns a JSON in the following format and I need to deserialize it. Attached image below where you can better visualize

```
{
    "491a21c9dfba2befd28fd2b7b4222d09460eef1728b2f11": {
        "found": true,
        "signature": "MTU4NDU0NTc0NjAxNjo0OTFhMjFjOWRmmQwMzA4MjRmYjU4YjBjYmI3Yzg5NDYwZWVmMTcyOGIyZjExOjEsMiwzLDQsNSw2LDcsODphMjQ0ZDRiZDM3ZTA1NzRiZTJiODMwNGNhNzllNDkyNGNmOWM0NWE3MWM3NDZiMThjOGQ2N2U1YmY2Y2U2MmZk",
        "sectors": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
    },
    "2e42dbd5df8e146eff500eb48e4c4daa6c4f11c": {
        "found": true,
        "signature": "MTU4NDU0NTc0NjAxNjoyZTQyZWE0M2U5ZjQ0MzBlMTQ2ZWZmNTAwZWI0OGU0YzRkYWE2YzRmMTFjOjEsMiw0LDUsNiw3LDg6YWU5NzA4YzdiZmZjM2RhOTU4NDg3MmEwYjc1OWIwZmZlZmRjMWZiNTJkZDcwNjcyZDZkYTZkN2Q3ZDFiYjQ4MA==",
        "sectors": ["1", "2", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
    },
    "fef3ab0a8d09dc77bcb8cbd313d484253a92f09b9a": {
        "found": false,
        "signature": "MTU4NDU0NTc0NjAxNjpmZWYzYWIwYThkMDlkY2I5NzNlNjdjYjU3MDdjNTZmMzEwZDc3N2JjYjhjYmQzMTNkNDg0MjUzYTkyZjA5YjlhOjphMGQ1MDZlOWZiOTFmNmNiOWQ1MWIxYzM2YzYyODEzYjFiYjgzZDc3NWEzNDZhMWNjY2I5ZjQwYmVjYjU3NGY0",
        "sectors": []
    }
}
```

I've created two classes

```
class UserInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("resultsInfo")]
    public Dictionary<string, ResultInfo> ResultsInfo { get; set; }
}

class ResultInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("_found")]
    public string Found { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty("_signature")]
    public string Signature { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty("sectors")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Sectors { get; set; }
}
```

The call is as follows but the result is always null

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var deserialize = serializer.Deserialize<UserInfo>(response.Content)
```

[image]

Can someone tell me how I can solve the problem? Thank you!

Comment: I never used `JavaScriptSerializer` but `newtonsoft.json` works great. May be you need to register converters?

Comment: I try Newtonsoft.Json and the result is the same...

Comment: You are using JavaScriptSerializer but have decorated your properties with JsonProperty attribute which is used by Newtonsoft (Json.Net). Try using JsonPropertyName attribute instead, or switch to Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Your JSON content does not seem to be compatible with what you are trying to deserialize it to. It looks like an array of objects, and in that case, you should try: `serializer.Deserialize<UserInfo[]>(response.Content)`

Comment: Sorry. `serializer.Deserialize<ResultInfo[]>(response.Content)`

Comment: the result what I get is System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using `Newtonsoft.Json`, however, the updates below should also work with `JavaScriptSerializer`.

Make a few changes and you should be able to deserialize the json.

```
class ResultInfo
{
    public bool Found { get; set; }
    public string Signature { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Sectors { get; set; }
}

// using Newtonsoft.Json;
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< Dictionary<string, ResultInfo> >(json);
```

The changes:

- Deserialize straight into `Dictionary<string, ResultInfo>`.  You don't need the wrapper class `UserInfo` unless your json starts like this: `{ "resultsInfo": ...`
- Remove the `[JsonProperty]` tags as some were incorrect and they're not required for the json you've shown.
- Update `Found` to `bool`.

[Example online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0FxWHQ)